# Pointer to member type incompatible with object when calling member function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, member-functions

**Problem**

I have an array of member function pointers that I assign at run-time. I am getting a compile-time error when attempting to call them:

> pointer to member type 'void (YCPU::)(uint16_t)' {aka 'void (YCPU::)(short unsigned int)'} incompatible with object type 'YCPUInstruction'`

I'm having trouble understanding the proper syntax to call the pointers.

**Code and Problem Details**

I have a struct `YCPUInstruction` that stores two member function pointers. These function pointers point to member functions inside `YCPU`. I store an array of `YCPUInstructions` and during initialization I call initialize which assigns these pointers to the correct member function.

Member function pointers and YCPUInstruction:

```cpp
typedef void (YCPU::*YCPUOpcode)(uint16_t opcode);
typedef std::string (YCPU::*YCPUDisassembler)(std::string name, uint16_t operand, uint16_t nextword, uint16_t address,
                                              bool show_memory_contents, uint16_t &instruction_size);


struct YCPUInstruction {
    std::string name;

    static YCPUOpcode opcode;
    static YCPUDisassembler disassembler;

    int cycles;
    bool is_nop;

    void initialize(std::string name, YCPUOpcode opcode, YCPUDisassembler disassembler, int cycles, bool is_NOP = false)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->opcode = opcode;
        this->disassembler = disassembler;
        this->cycles = cycles;
        this->is_nop = is_NOP;
    }
};
```

YCPU

```cpp
class YCPU
{
public:
    // YCPUOpcode points to one these functions (many more than these 3, just examples)
    void NOP(uint16_t opcode);
    void ADC(uint16_t opcode);
    void ADD(uint16_t opcode);
    ...
    // YCPUDisassembler points to one of these functions (many more than these 2, just examples)
    std::string disassemble_ALU(std::string name, uint16_t operand, uint16_t nextword, uint16_t address,
                             bool show_memory_contents, uint16_t &instruction_size);
    std::string disassemble_BRA(std::string name, uint16_t operand, uint16_t nextword, uint16_t address,
                             bool show_memory_contents, uint16_t &instruction_size);
    ...
private:
    std::array<YCPUInstruction, 256> opcodes;
};
```

During setup, I initialize the opcodes like so:

```cpp
void YCPU::initialize_opcodes()
{
    opcodes[0x01].initialize("CMP", &YCPU::CMP, &YCPU::disassemble_ALU, 0);
    opcodes[0x02].initialize("CMP", &YCPU::CMP, &YCPU::disassemble_ALU, 0);
    opcodes[0x03].initialize("CMP", &YCPU::CMP, &YCPU::disassemble_ALU, 0);
    ... // and so on for all instructions 
}
```

After initialization, I attempt to call the member functions like so:

```
void YCPU::run_one_instruction()
{
    ...
    uint16_t word = read_mem_int16(PC, SI_CS); // 0x1-0xff
    YCPUInstruction op = opcodes[word & 0xFFFF];
    (op.*YCPUInstruction::opcode)(word);
    ...
}
```

However, that throws the compiler error I mentioned above.

If I dereference `op` first, like so:

```cpp
(op->*YCPUInstruction::opcode)(word);
```

I get this error:

> error: no match for 'operator->*' (operand types are 'YCPUInstruction' and 'YCPUOpcode' {aka 'void (YCPU::*)(short unsigned int)'})

If I change the syntax to this:

```cpp
(op->*opcode)(word);
```

or:

```cpp
(op.*opcode)(word)
```

I get this error

> error: 'opcode' was not declared in this scope

**What is the specific syntax I need to use to call these member function pointers?**

Comment: Based on your error message, it sounds like you're trying to use a `YCPUInstruction` instead of a `YCPUOpcode`.  What type is `op`?

Comment: op is a YCPUInstruction. Apologies I'll update the code to show it's type and how it gets assigned

Comment: Those types describe functions which are members of `YCPU`. So what is the `YCPU` object which you want `this` to point at inside those functions?

Comment: You've defined `opcode` as `static`, yet you're trying to treat it as a member variable. Which is it meant to be?

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde any chance you could link me some information on the difference? I was just listening to my IDE and forgot I added that identifier. YCPU is the parent object that stores op and calls it

Comment: `op` has to be a `YCPU`.  It's what becomes `this` in the member function.

Comment: @StephenNewell ah ok. Is there some way to point to a member function from an outside struct. i.e. keep it as YCPUInstruction, store that Instruction inside YPCU and call  YCPU::member_function?

Comment: If your member functions don't need access to the state of a `YCPU` object you can make them `static` and use them like a normal function pointer.  If they do need to access the object's state then you need to call them on a `YCPU` object.

Comment: @0x003 Have a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static
Long story short, instances do not contain `static` variables - they are only associated with the class (struct). Non-`static` variables are actually present in each instance.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde understood, thanks I've removed static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left operand of `.*` must refer to / the left operand of `->*` must point at an object of the member function's containing class. The right operand can be any expression which gives the pointer-to-member value.

The containing class of the member functions you're using is `YCPU`, so it's not correct to have the `YCPUInstruction` as a left operand. I see that your expression is within another member function of `YCPU`, so assuming you want to use `*this` as the `YCPU` the function is called on, you want `this->*`. The following expression can be an ordinary `.` or `->` expression to just get, not call, the pointer-to-member-function value from the `YCPUInstruction`. Since the precedence of `.*` and `->*` are strange, excessive parentheses are quite often necessary and always recommended.

```
void YCPU::run_one_instruction()
{
    // ...
    uint16_t word = read_mem_int16(PC, SI_CS); // 0x1-0xff
    YCPUInstruction op = opcodes[word & 0xFFFF];
    (this->*(op.opcode))(word);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In "The containing class of your function pointers is `YCPU`" I think you meant the class of the "member functions"?  The pointer-to-member is in fact a data member of `YCPUInstruction`, pointing to a function member of `YCPU`.